# Can't access Sites folder on OS X 10.10 (Yosemite)

Tags: osx-yosemite

My **Sites** folder was working fine on 10.9 but when i upgraded to 10.10, it stopped working. By that I mean, when I type:

```
http://localhost/
```

I get correct message. But when I try to access any file stored in Sites folder, it says:

```
NOT FOUND 404
```

I double checked everything.

- httpd.conf
- username.conf

But it still doesn't works.

Comment: For the record, Yosemite is labelled beta software, you should expect problems with it. The proper procedure for this is to seek help on the Apple forums.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a browser other than Safari?

I noticed this as well and have had success accessing local applications in Chrome.
Haven't found a reason why Safari is blocking connections to any localhost addresses though.

Comment: same problem

i just copied the folders from SITES folder to Library/WebServer/Documents
. This is pain tbh